# User wildfly does not exist

Tags: linux, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am trying to run wildfly-init-debian.sh to run wildfly on starup but when I run the file it gives

```
"user wildfly does not exist..."
```

error.

How can I define this user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is almost certainly trying to start WildFly as the debian user `wildfly`. You will need to create this user and make sure it has correct permissions for your WildFly directories.

The most easy way is to run

```
useradd wildfly
```

[More detailed instructions can easily be found online](http://www.tecmint.com/add-users-in-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
useradd -r wildfly
```

this will create a dedicated system user for wildfly.